# Multiple Select Statements for count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a one table called data.It has few columns as i mentioned below.What i need to do is i want to get count for attributes in those columns.right now i am getting count for those attributes.but the same time it print other columns as well.i have attach an image. from that just i want product and total columns.also like that i want Courier and Total in another view..what should i do?[image]

Here is my code

```
SELECT Product, Courier, Acc_No, Name, Delivered_Date, 
    Month, Bill_Run, Status, Remarks, count(id) as Total  
FROM data 
    WHERE ID = ID
    [AND Product = "{pro_id,false}"]
    [AND Courier = "{cou_id,false}"]
    [AND Bill_Run = "{bill_id,false}"]
    [AND Dispatch_Type = "{dis_id,false}"]
    [AND Status = "{sta_id,false}"]
    [AND Acc_No = "{acc_no,false}"]
    [AND Name = "{name,false}"]
    [AND Delivered_Date between {date_range,RANGE1} and {date_range,RANGE2}] 
    ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: just remove the extra columns that you don't need from `SELECT` keep only those that you need

Comment: @SaqibAmin its ok.but what i need to do is i want to calculate total for other attributes also

Comment: @colombo which other attributes?

Comment: @PathikVejani i want to separete items in one column from one query.i have update another image plz have a look.from there i just need Courier and Total columns,like that i want to count for all the columns from one queryin different views.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please remove the tag that doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For First One:

```
SELECT Product,
       count(id) AS Total
FROM DATA
WHERE ID = ID [AND Product = "{pro_id,false}"][
  AND Courier = "{cou_id,false}"][
  AND Bill_Run = "{bill_id,false}"][
  AND Dispatch_Type = "{dis_id,false}"][
  AND Status = "{sta_id,false}"][
  AND Acc_No = "{acc_no,false}"][
  AND Name = "{name,false}"][
  AND Delivered_Date BETWEEN {date_range,
                              RANGE1} AND {date_range,
                                           RANGE2}]
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

For Second View:

```
SELECT Courier,
       count(id) AS Total
FROM DATA
WHERE ID = ID [AND Product = "{pro_id,false}"][
  AND Courier = "{cou_id,false}"][
  AND Bill_Run = "{bill_id,false}"][
  AND Dispatch_Type = "{dis_id,false}"][
  AND Status = "{sta_id,false}"][
  AND Acc_No = "{acc_no,false}"][
  AND Name = "{name,false}"][
  AND Delivered_Date BETWEEN {date_range,
                              RANGE1} AND {date_range,
                                           RANGE2}]
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: in first one change this: `ORDER BY ID ASC` not `ORDER BY ID AS`

Comment: @PathikVejani Corrected, Thanks

Comment: @SaqibAmin I want to do this from one query is there any way?

Comment: If you want to do that in one query, then in you will see three columns in one result, one for Product, one for Courier and one for Total.
Just replace the `SELECT` Part with: `SELECT Courier, Product, count(id) AS Total FROM DATA`

Comment: @SaqibAmin yep its ok.i want like this product & total in one view only these two columns.Courier and total in one view only these two columns.to do that in one query is there anyway?

Comment: Nope, that is not possible in one query, you will have to write two queries to achieve that result as in above answer